# Handling Posix signals in a library

Tags: c++, linux, signals, posix

Is it possible to somehow handle Posix signals twice? I need to perform some actions when the process terminates in a library I'm writing. I do it simply like this:

```
signal(SIGSEGV, sig_handler);
signal(SIGABRT, sig_handler);
signal(SIGFPE, sig_handler);
signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);
```

This works but is not entirely acceptable as the user of my library may want to handle the signals himself for other reasons. I suppose I would therefore interfere by doing it.

Would it be possible to somehow handle the signal in my sig_handler and then to "rethrow" it so that it is available transparently for anyone else needing it? By "transparently" I also mean that I don't want to ask the user to provide some "custom callbacks", as my library has a defined interface already, no real header. I need some callback in any case the process terminates, install transparently for the user and handle transparently for the user. Is there anything like this? It is sufficient this solution works on Linux. Thanks!

Comment: What actions are you hoping to perform after a `SIGABRT` or `SIGSEGV`?

Comment: I need to kill a process and send a string to a device. I know it is difficult/impossible after SIGSEGV as very few calls are allowed but I don't care. I do the best I can and if it does not work I'll live with it. More relevant is SIGINT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is probably to use sigaction to get the current callback and place yours in the middle. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17102919/it-is-valid-to-have-multiple-signal-handlers-for-same-signal) explains it. However if the application sets it after you do you won't see any call at all.

To get the current one:

```
struct sigaction sa;
sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, &sa);
...
```

To set yours:

```
struct sigaction sa;
...
sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
```

In your callback you call the first one.