# Multiple signal handlers for the same signal e.g. SIGALRM

Tags: c, signals

I have a sample program which triggers SIGALRM every second. Following is my code.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t _flag = false;

void _sigHandler( int signal )
{
    _flag = true;
}

int main()
{
    signal( SIGALRM, _sigHandler );
    alarm( 1 );

    while (true)
    {
        if ( _flag)
        {
            printf( "SIGALRM received\n" );
            _flag = false;
            alarm( 1 );
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, is it possible to have multiple signal handlers for the same signal based on the parameter passed to the alarm(); method. E.g. if I call alarm(1) and alarm(2), two different method has to be called.
Well, my idea of using an alarm here is, I want to call three different method in 3 different time intervals. e.g call func1(); after every X seconds, call func2() after every Y seconds and call func3() after every Z seconds and this runs in an infinite while loop. IF the idea of alarm doesn't fit here then any other hint/help is appreciated.

Comment: No.  There is exactly one disposition for each signal (type).  You can register the same function to handle more than one kind of signal, but you cannot register more than one function to handle the same kind of signal.

Comment: If `funcX` is suppose to run every `X` seconds, and `funcY` is suppose to run every `Y` seconds, call `funcX` if it's been `X` seconds since the last time it was called, and call `funcY` if it's been `Y` seconds since the last time it was called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it valid to have multiple signal handlers for same signal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17102919/6850771)

Comment: As to multiplexing timeout signals, I wrote an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12765121/1475978).

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to have multiple signal handlers for the same signal based on the parameter passed to the alarm().

No. There can only be one signal handler at anytime for a signal. If you install many, the last one is the only one in effect.

> if I call alarm(1) and alarm(2), two different method has to be called.

`alarm()` raises SIGALRM after the specified interval. It doesn't know even know/care if there's a signal handler for SIGALRM, let alone "multiple" signal handlers. In short, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use one signal handler per signal. The last signal handler in the code is the one used, meaning that if you write:

```
signal(SIGALRM, signal_handler_1);

/* do some l33t stuff */

signal(SIGALRM, signal_handler_2);
```

`SIGALRM` will be handled by `signal_handler_2`.